# Laravel - prevent file access outside of public while deployment is in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8, vhosts

I am relatively new to laravel so pardon me if it is a bad practice.
I have a godaddy domain lets say example.com which is pointed to my ec2 instance.
I have 2 projects example.com website and Admin.
so my folder structure is

- /var/www/html

  - website
  - admin

I wanted to point example.com to point /website so I managed that from virtual host like below

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/website"
</VirtualHost>
```

This works as expected.

now I wanted to access admin panel by `example.com/admin`
for that, I created symlink in /website as admin which is pointing to /admin folder.
With above aproach, I can access admin using `example.com/admin/public` which is as per my expectation as all users are already using /public url.
Now the problem is when I access  `example.com/admin/` without public, it shows all the files outside of public and also I can see the .env file using url. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a good solution
First, I added `.htaccess` file with following lines

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^ public [L]
```

This redirected everything to /public

Second, for extra security, I restricted access to .env file using

```
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Still I would like to have some suggesions if any. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Virtual Host configuration, restrict Listing via `Options` directive

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/website"
<Directory "/var/www/html/website">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Furthermore, in virtual host configuration, you can restrict individual files as well from public access like this

```
<Files composer.json>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>

<Files .env>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
```

Comment: Thank you. <Files> tag was useful.